# Trouble with compiling multiple files

Tags: c++

I have 3 files:

use.cpp:

```
#include "my.h"
int main() 
{
    foo = 7;
    print_foo();
    print(99);
}
```

my.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my.h"
void print_foo()
{
    std::cout << foo;
}
void print(int i)
{
    std::cout << i;
}
```

my.h:

```
extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);
```

I get these errors when I compile and I have no idea whats wrong:

/tmp/ccYyefjH.o: In function `main':
use.cpp:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to`foo'
/tmp/ccIgQsal.o: In function `print_foo()':
my.cpp:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to`foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I typed in

```
g++ -o use use.cpp my.cpp
```

Comment: Where is `foo` actually defined?

Comment: `extern int foo; ` does not define a variable, it tells compiler that in some other module exists int variable called foo.

Comment: @London - No, it's defined `extern`, telling the compiler to "know `foo` exists", but "look elsewhere for the real definition."

Comment: @London: No, that's a _declaration_. You still need a _definition_. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574403/560648